# How to pass a variable from onclick another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to pass a variable from onclick another function. The content is created at runtime so I use `on()` of JQuery and don't know how to pass the variable.

```
<a class="call" href="#" onclick="call('.$id['id'].');">...</a>
```

Here the js:

```
$('.call').on("click", function(id) {
    alert(id);
});
```

The alert responds `[object Object]`

Are not you supposed to be like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
<a class="call" href="#" id="'.$id['id'].'">...</a>


$('.call').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // unless you need to follow the link too
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<a class="call" href="#" onclick="call('.$id['id'].');">...</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="#" onclick="call('<?php echo $id['id']; ?>')">...</a>
```

and Change:

```
$('.call').on("click", function(id) {
    alert(id);
});
```

To:

```
function call(id)
{
    alert(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was fine, but the other was the one that interested me, I may not have explained well. Also the script is loaded at that point not loaded at the beginning.